# Добавить спрайт SVG через WordPress на страницу

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Новичок, прошу принять и простить если что.
Пытаюсь добавить спрайт SVG c `id=logo` через админ панель, что бы пользователь мог менять сам лого сайта и добавлять самостоятельно новый спрайт.
На понимаю где нужно указать ID в путь, что бы картинка качала отображаться и в панеле и при добавлении.
В исходном шаблоне спрайт добавлен на страницу так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Из документации добавил все функции  в `functions.php`:

Сам исходник svg файла такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При добавлении спрайта в админку выводится пустым.

При переходе во вкладку изменить медиа файл, поля для добавления ID не нашел. есть поле с путем к файлу, но добавить туда ID не возможно.

В `functions.php`  добавил `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );`

В хедере прописываю значение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Во внешнем виде -> настройки  добавляю логотип. В ссылке на логотип изменений сделать не могу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Естественно ничего не выводится на сайт.

При замене элемента, как в исходнике все прекрасно появляется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добавил плагин SVG spritemap, но твм ничего поменять нельзя:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что спрайт стал виден.
пересмотрел кучу видео единственное, где увидел про id это в этой статье.
Но там не описано как добавлять ID и где можно указать спрайту путь с id.
https://oddstyle.ru/wordpress-2/wordpress-plaginy/sozdaem-i-nastraivaem-svg-sprajty-v-media-biblioteke-wordpress.html
Может подскажите литературу какую почитать или видео посмотреть.
Не понимаю как сделать.

P.S. нужно добаление Id только через панель, чтобы пользователь ничего не менял, не исправлял, не добавлял в самом коде.